# How do I correct Quick Access folder links?

Tags: windows-10, file-management, shortcuts, user-folders

I am using Windows 10 and I have moved my Documents, Pictures, Downloads and Videos folders to D:\ by changing their location properies within file explorer.  Now, if I click the quick access folder for Documents or Pictures an error message comes up saying

> C:\Users\username\Documents is unavailable.  If the location is
>   on this PC, make sure that the device or drive is connected or the
>   disc is inserted, then try again.  If the location is on a network,
>   make sure that you are connected to the network or internet, then try
>   again.  If the location still can't be found, it might have been moved
>   or deleted.

or

> C:\Users\username\Pictures is unavailable.  If the location is
>   on this PC, make sure that the device or drive is connected or the
>   disc is inserted, then try again.  If the location is on a network,
>   make sure that you are connected to the network or internet, then try
>   again.  If the location still can't be found, it might have been moved
>   or deleted.

If I go to 'File Explorer' the links within there are correct.

When trying to pin the correct folder to Quick Access it will not do it.

When trying to unpin the incorrect folder previously pinned to Quick Access automatically by windows, it will not do it.

The problem only applies to the Documents and Pictures folders.  The Videos and Downloads folders within Quick Access are correct.

How can I correct the links within the incorrect Quick Access folders?

Answer (score 0):

File Explorer's Quick Access Pane predefines User's Libraries and it doesn't allow you to unpin them or change them with a folder that has same name.
But you can change the directory where it looks to find these folder.

1. Right Click + Properties + Location Tab

[image]

As you realize there is a move button for particularly your intention to move the folder to another directory.