# How to detach deleted folder from quick access

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have a link to a deleted folder in "quick access" (frequent folders). However, I cannot remove it, because when I try to "unpin" it I get an error "Location is not available".

Somewhat related to "[How do I correct Quick Access folder links?](https://superuser.com/q/1063633/72397)", but with no applicable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer above was useful, but did not work for me. Clear did simply not clean it up. However, I have found a way to get rid of it.

I have tried to unpin it with the little "pin icon" next to the entry. This did not show any result. However, there is also a "unpin" context menu entry (right mouse). This for some reason did work.

[image: Pin Icons]

Answer (score 2):

> However, I cannot remove it, because when I try to "unpin" it I get an
> error "Location is not available".

1. Open Folder Options
2. Click the **Clear** button

[image]

An alternative solution is to recreate the folder and/or file that is pinned to `Quick access` and then unpin the location.

You can also remove the Quick access Shortcuts themselves by doing the following:

> 1. Navigate to `AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations` within File
>    Explorer
> 2. Delete `f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms`
> 3. Reboot

Source: [[Fix] Quick access Pinned Shortcuts Stuck or Not Working (Windows 10)](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-quick-access-reset-pinned-shortcuts-stuck-not-working-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Click%20Quick%20access.,choose%20Unpin%20from%20Quick%20access.)

Answer (score 2):

## Remove Quick Access Unpin History For All Users

*Some machines exhibit the same error not allowing old pins to be undone.*

1. In [Windows 10 Open powershell as admin](https://superuser.com/questions/108207/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-as-administrator)
2. Copy and Paste: `Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms -Force` into powershell and hit enter.
3. Close and reopen file explorer. Done. The quick accesss pin customisations and history has deleted on all user profiles on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. I managed to only make it work by creating the folder in question, renaming it to ensure that Windows knew it matched the QuickAccess pin, and then deleting the folder. Don't know if that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This works

1. Run powershell as admin
2. Paste the following and hit enter:

   Remove-Item -Path C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms -Force

Comment: Same as https://superuser.com/a/1636189/72397 , or?

Comment: This worked https://superuser.com/a/1636189/72397