# How can I get rid of some non-functioning QUICK ACCESS folder icons that I originally created?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-quick-access

I'm having a little problem. I recently moved some folders around a bit a while ago, and now some of my QUICK ACCESS folders don't work because they're now pointing to the wrong location. Of course, it's easy to simply add new folders to the QUICK ACCESS area for where their new location are.

But the old, non-working versions won't go away. I've tried to Right-Click on both the QUICK ACCESS shortcut and on the "real" folder (in the new location) and neither option give me any option in the menu to "REMOVE FROM QUICK ACCESS".

I even created a folder back where it used to be, and tried to Right-Click that, but it, too, didn't have an option to Remove.

I came across a similar question here on the site here: ([Where are the Win 10 Quick Access settings stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/1051440/where-are-the-win-10-quick-access-settings-stored?newreg=aff10169aa2b498a8b15528dd5a6ecf3))

But even though it talks about a folder that contains all the AUTOMATICDESTINATIONS, I have about 550 of them in there, and the contents are not readable to be able to delete the correct ones. Plus, for what it's worth, when I open my QUICK ACCESS folder in the normal way, I've only got 22 icons in there (3 of which I'd like to remove). Thus, I'm guessing that quite a few of the 550 of them are for something else.

Does anyone have a suggestion about how I could either gracefully or forcefully remove the unwanted QUICK ACCESS icons that I have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detach deleted folder from quick access](https://superuser.com/questions/1283401/how-to-detach-deleted-folder-from-quick-access)

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Quick Access, select Options, and in the lower section click on Clear to clear File History. This will remove the older entries you do not want.